# Formulario.java:28: error: cannot find symbol BotaoAction action = new BotaoAction(t);

Tags: java, swing, gui, awt

Ah, então eu estava criando um programa com a Swing, ele*texto grifado* lê o nome que o usuário coloca, e depois mostra pra ele, coisa bem simples, ainda sou bem novato, mas quando eu criei a classe "BotaoAction" (que era ela que mostrava o nome do usuário) eu iniciei o código e deu o seguinte erro

```
    Formulario.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    BotaoAction action = new BotaoAction(t);
    ^
```

código usado:

```
package swing;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Formulario{

    public static void main(String[] args){

       JFrame f = new JFrame();
       f.setTitle("Janela");
       f.setSize(300,200);
       f.setLocation(500,300);
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       JPanel p = new JPanel();

       JLabel one = new JLabel("Digite seu nome:");
       p.add(one);

       JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
       p.add(t);

       JButton b = new JButton("OK");
       BotaoAction action = new BotaoAction(t);
       b.addActionListener(action);
       p.add(b);

       f.add(p);
       f.setVisible(true);

     }

 }
```

código que usei na classe "BotaoAction":

```
package swing;

public class BotaoAction implements ActionListener{

    private JTextField t;
    public BotaoAction(JTextField t){
        this.t = t;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        String nome = t.getText();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Foi digitedo" + nome);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui eu testei e funcionou normalmente. Se tiver executando através do terminal ou prompt de comando, compilando e executando a classe dentro do próprio diretório "swing", tente através do comando abaixo:

```
java -cp ../ swing.Formulario
```

isso definirá o diretório logo acima como raiz da execução, e assim você consegue executar a classe informando o package dela junto.

Se for apenas para testes e não precisar realmente de uma hierarquia de pacotes agora, remova `package swing` de ambas as classes, recompile-as e simplesmente execute `java Formulario` diretamente da pasta swing, que funcionará da mesma forma.